# Processing Text for Classification with Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, text-classification

I'm trying to train a basic text classification NN using Keras. I download 12,500 pos and 12,500 negative movie reviews from a website. I'm having trouble processing the data into something Keras can use however.

First, I open the 25000 text files and store each file into an array. I then run each array (one positive and one negative) through this function:

```
def process_for_model(textArray):
    '''
     Given a 2D array of the form:
     [[fileLines1],[fileLines2]...[fileLinesN]]
     converts the text into integers
    '''
    result = []
    for file_ in textArray:
        inner = []
        for line in file_:
            length = len(set(text_to_word_sequence(line)))
            inner.append(hashing_trick(line,round(length*1.3),hash_function='md5'))
        result.append(inner)

    return result
```

With the purpose of converting the words into numbers to get them close to something a Keras model can use.

I then append the converted numbers into a single array, along with appending a 0 or 1 to another array as labels:

```
training_labels = []
train_batches = []
for i in range(len(positive_encoded)):
    train_batches.append(positive_encoded[i])
    training_labels.append([0])
for i in range(len(negative_encoded)):
    train_batches.append(negative_encoded[i])
    training_labels.append([1])
```

And finally I convert each array to a np array:

```
train_batches = array(train_batches)
training_labels = array(training_labels)
```

However, I'm not really sure where to go from here. Each review is, I believe, 168 words. I don't know how to create an appropriate model for this data or how to properly scale all the numbers to be between 0 and 1 using sklearn.

The things I am most confused on are: how many layers should I have, how many neurons each layer should have, and how many input dimensions should I have for the first layer.

Should I be taking another approach entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is quite a good tutotial with Keras and this dataset: https://machinelearningmastery.com/predict-sentiment-movie-reviews-using-deep-learning/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Keras official tutorial for text classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_text_classification).

It basically downloads 50k reviews from the IMDB set, equally balanced (half positive, half negative). They split (randomly) half for training, half for testing, and take 10k (40%) of the training examples as a validation set.

```
imdb = keras.datasets.imdb    
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)
```

The reviews are already in their word-dictionary representation (i.e. each review is an array of numbers). The total dictionary has about 80k+ words, but they only use the top 10k most frequent words (all the other words in a particular review are mapped to a special token - unknown (`'<UNK>'`)).

(In the tutorial they create a reversed word dictionary - for the sake of showing you the original reviews. But it's not important.)

Each review is max 256 words, so they pre-process each review and pad it with 0 (`<PAD>` token) in case it's shorter. (Padding is done post, i.e. at the end)

```
train_data = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(train_data,
                                                        value=word_index["<PAD>"],
                                                        padding='post',
                                                        maxlen=256)
test_data = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(test_data,
                                                       value=word_index["<PAD>"],
                                                       padding='post',
                                                       maxlen=256)
```

Their NN architecture consists of 4 layers:

1. Input Embedding layer: takes a batch of reviews, each a 256 vector who's numbers are [0, 10,000) and tries to find a 16 dimensional vector (for each word) to represent them.
2. Global Average Pooling layer: average over all the words (16-D representation) in a review, and gives you a single 16 dimensional vector to represent the whole review.
3. Fully connected dense layer of 16 nodes - the 'vanilla' NN layer. They chose a ReLu activation function.
4. An output layer of 1 node: with a sigmoid activation function - gives a number from 0 to 1 which represents the confidence it's a positive/negative review.

Here is the code for it:

```
vocab_size = 10000    
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 16))
model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))
```

Then they fit the model and run it:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit(partial_x_train,
                    partial_y_train,
                    epochs=40,
                    batch_size=512,
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
                    verbose=1)
```

In summary - they chose to simplify what could have been a 10k dimensional vector to only 16 dimensions, and then run one dense layer NN - with which they got a pretty good results (87%).